# Maybe the Thread is in a different state?

Tags: c#

The condition is not true, and the execution occurs, how come?

Wav.Checked is always true, the recorder has not been null for a long time, and I have shown the status of the stream .. but the program climbs on GoWA () ...

Why?

Maybe the Thread is in a different state, tried to add || recorder.ThreadState! = ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin - the same result..

[shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCuOZ.png)

```
Thread recorder;
void GoWA() {
    ParentPtr = this.Handle;
    recorder = new Thread(new ThreadStart(GoWithWA));
    recorder.Start();
}
private void GoWithWA() {
    Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
    StartWA();
    waitor.Reset();
    while (!waitor.WaitOne(50)){
    }
    WA.waveInReset(phwi);
    GC.KeepAlive(waCallback_);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should add more context, maybe some piece of code?

Comment: First advice, is stop using the Thread class unless you absolutely know you need to, and use Task

Answer (score 0):

Use better `recorder.IsAlive` instead of checking ThreadState

It's hard to foresee in what state a thread is.. For your purpose `IsAlive` would be better.